# Understanding "LOG: execute S_1: BEGIN " in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, logging

I turned on the Postgres logging with 'all' and logs show `LOG:  execute S_1: BEGIN`.

What does `S_1` mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The format of this log entry denotes the use of the [extended query protocol](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/protocol-flow.html#PROTOCOL-FLOW-EXT-QUERY).

From the linked doc:

> In the extended protocol, the frontend first sends a Parse message,
>   which contains a textual query string, optionally some information
>   about data types of parameter placeholders, and the **name of a
>   destination prepared-statement object** (an empty string selects the
>   unnamed prepared statement)

The `S_1` from the log corresponds to that name.

If the application uses the `libpq` C library or a layer based on it, libpq functions like `PQprepare`, `PQexecPrepared` or `PQexecParams` are built on the  extended protocol.
On the other hand, the older `PQExec` uses the simple query protocol only.

Answer (score 2):

The BEGIN was wrapped into a prepare statement which was given the name "S_1".  The name is probably automatically generated by whatever library you are using to connect to PostgreSQL.